# Create a button to control background music on and off in pygame

Tags: python, button, pygame, game-development

I want to create a button in my game that can control the background music on and off. The first click will stop the background music, and the second click can bring back the music. Now my button can control the music on and off, but I need to click multiple times to make it work, it seems that the click event is not captured everytime, here is my code:

```
 for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if 20 + 50 > mouse_position[0] > 20 and 20 + 20 > mouse_position[1] > 20:
                play_music = not play_music
                if play_music:
                    pygame.mixer.music.unpause()
                else:
                    pygame.mixer.music.pause()

  pygame.display.flip()
  clock = pygame.time.Clock()
  clock.tick(15)
```

Answer (score 7):

J0hn's answer is correct. Define a boolean variable (e.g. `music_paused = False`), toggle it when the user clicks on the button and call `pygame.mixer.music.pause` to stop the music and `pygame.mixer.music.unpause` to resume the playback of the music stream.

I also recommend doing the collision check in the event loop (`for event in pygame.event.get():`), because the button should be clicked only once per `pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` event. `pygame.mouse.get_pressed()` will keep clicking the music button as long as the mouse button is down.

```
import pygame as pg


pg.init()
screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
clock = pg.time.Clock()
BG_COLOR = pg.Color('gray12')
BLUE = pg.Color('dodgerblue1')
pg.mixer.music.load('your_music_file.ogg')
pg.mixer.music.play(-1)

button = pg.Rect(100, 150, 90, 30)
music_paused = False

done = False
while not done:
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            done = True
        elif event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if button.collidepoint(event.pos):
                # Toggle the boolean variable.
                music_paused = not music_paused
                if music_paused:
                    pg.mixer.music.pause()
                else:
                    pg.mixer.music.unpause()

    screen.fill(BG_COLOR)
    pg.draw.rect(screen, BLUE, button)
    pg.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)

pg.quit()
```

Comment: I edited my code and it works now, but sometimes I have to click multiple times to make it works. I updated my code in the question, please see my update.

Comment: Your example is incomplete (always post [minimal but complete examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), but I think I see what's causing the problem. In the event loop you have to check if the event was a `pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` event instead of `if click[0] == 1:`. Just replace this line with `if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:` and it should work.

Comment: I updated the code again, but still it's not always working. I mean when I click, it sometimes can pause|unpause, sometimes it cannot. Is it because of the clock rate?

Comment: That's still no complete example. Add all code that's needed to run it and to reproduce the error. The indentation seems to be incorrect, but I'm not sure if that's the reason for the bug or if it happened when you pasted the code here.

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you have a `pygame.mixer.music.pause()` but nothing from `resume`.  I'm not sure how pygame's music mixer works but I'd recommend using a flag that is updated on button click

`music = 0` by default, if clicked, set `music = 1` then have a check `if music == 1: pygame.mixer.music.pause()` and `if music == 0: pygame.mixer.music.unpause()`.  Make that check and flag change every time the button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

ya guys don't need a boolean variable only a small function

```
def toggleMusic():
    if pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
       pygame.mixer.music.pause()

    else:
       pygame.mixer.music.unpause()
```

pygame.mixer.music.get_busy() is the boolean you need because this checks if music is playing. if music is playing it will return True and vice versa

Comment: How can OP use `toggleMusic` function? The function is not returning any variable and no input parameter. Please update your answer.